# How to inject material component from a directive?

Tags: angular-material

Is there a way to inject a material component from a directive, using renderer2?

In my case, I try to make a directive that show a mat-progress-spinner in a mat-button.

For example, here is a directive. This code is doing something similar to what I am trying to do. Since I am using Angular Material in my project, I would like to add a Material Component called mat-progress-spinner instead of this simple gif

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appButtonLoader]'
})
export class ButtonLoaderDirective {
  img: HTMLImageElement;

  @Input() set appButtonLoader(value: boolean) {
  this.toggle(value);
}

constructor(private element:ElementRef) {
  this.img = document.createElement('img');
  this.img.src = 'https://www.winston.com/cached/40181/images/spinner-white.gif';
  this.toggle(this.appButtonLoader);
}

toggle(condition: boolean) {
  condition ? this.show() : this.hide()
}

show() {
  this.element.nativeElement.appendChild(this.img);
}

hide() {
  this.img.remove();
}
```

}

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/load-button-directive?file=app%2Fbutton-loader.directive.ts

Comment: Minor changes to improve the readability of your question. But I suggest you try things yourself, and rather add some [mcve]. Questions that contain "own effort" often receive more helpful feedback compared to "here is a requirement, how to do that" style questions.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found here : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

In my case, this was not enough because Mat-Button is not a ViewContainerRef, so I can't createComponent.

The final solution was to createComponent then to move it with Renderer2.appendChild

Stackblitz updated : https://stackblitz.com/edit/load-button-directive?file=app%2Fbutton-loader2.directive.ts

Comment: Awesome work buddy, just what I wanted :) (Upvoted for both question and answer)